# Son accidentally painted my new cedar shake! How do I remove it?

Tags: paint, removal

I just spent two days prepping my natural cedar shake for the beautiful stain I purchased today only to come home and find that my son had PAINTED IT!  What can I do to remove the blue Pittsburg top of the line paint that is currently drying on my beautiful shake that I intended to stain today?

Comment: Oh man that is awful. It'd be funny if it were an episode of "I Love Lucy".  Did he prime first?

Comment: Disaster.  Maybe you can sell the story to one of those TV reality shows.

Comment: Make your son clean it up with some toxic paint removers? Just kidding. If you like the color, keep it, otherwise it's probably buying-more-shakes time.

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely pain removers out there at the local hardware. They have lots of fumes though so you'll want to be ventilated (:

Comment: I have to wonder if the trouble and expense (and health, many paint strippers have methylene chloride: carcinogen) of removing the paint would be worth it. Maybe just learn to live with it painted.